# :: (scope resolution operator) is used for multiple purposes in C++?

Tags: c++

I am learning C++, and want to confirm few thins. I have seen that `std::cin` has :: operator which means that iostream.h file must have **cin** related code inside **namespace std**. Whereas if you include `myclass.h` and have class NOT inside namespace like this

```
//myclass.h
class x { void func(){}};
```

Then you don't need to do this `myclass:x.func();` **Instead** i can do just this `x.func();`. Correct Becuase it's not inside namespace.

Secondly, `::` can be used to **define** class functions outside of the class like in their cpp file. Correct?

Now my additional question is that are these two functions separate or one? do they just look different to me?

Comment: It's a scope resolution operator, so it is unnecessary if you are in the scope of a class, as you pointed out, but is necessary if you are later defining a function outside the class.  AFAIK, you cannot declare a class function outside of the actual class scope, only define a declared one, but I could be wrong.

Comment: i didn't mean to say cin had operator overloaded. What i am saying that you need `std::` part in `std::cin` because code inside `#include <iostream>` must **reside** inside `namespace std` and if it was **not** inside namespace then we won't need `std::` part Correct? Like we don't need for over custom class in which code does not reside inside namespace.

Comment: ...and yes so far i have learned that function of a class can be declared inside class only but be defined outside too.

Comment: Yes, that's correct, I realized that's what you meant on second reading.  I also double checked, you must declare a function in a class' scope before defining it, so you could not put something like `void x::otherfunc()` in your cpp file without declaring it in the class scope.

Comment: everyone thanks a lot...this is a lot of new information to me..so ill look at it again for some days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have seen that std::cin has :: operator which means that `iostream.h` file must have cin related code inside namespace std.

I realize this isn't a question, but you said `iostream.h` and I wanted to point out that you should not use `iostream.h` because it is deprecated, use `iostream` instead.

> Then you don't need to do this myclass:x.func(); Instead i can do just this x.func();. Correct Becuase it's not inside namespace.

This is correct.  You could do the same thing if all of your code was inside a namespace rather than a class.

> Secondly, :: can be used to define class functions outside of the class like in their cpp file. Correct?

Correct, so long as they have been declared, but not defined, in the class scope this is allowed and usually considered preferable for readability.

> Now my additional question is that are these two functions separate or one? do they just look different to me?

If both are in the class scope already, `void x::func(){}` and `void func(){}` result in the same thing (one would call both by using `x a; a.func()`, for example).

EDIT:  In response to the comment, you can define a namespace basically the same way you define a class, as:

```
namespace funcs
{
    void innerfunc(){}
    void outerfunc();
    void funcs::scopedfunc(){}
}
funcs::outerfunc();
```

As you can infer from `std`, these are called as free functions, rather than being called from an object like a non-static class function.

```
int main()
{
    funcs::innerfunc();
    using namespace funcs;
    outerfunc();
}
```

Comment: "You could do the same thing if all of your code was inside a namespace rather than a class" ...just to be clear by "same thing" you mean put `myclass::`...can you explain that part more

Comment: the word **free functions** is very important to me now

Comment: what's up with `funcs::scopedfunc()`

Comment: @MuhammadUmer I just put it there to show that you could declare the function with or without explicitly using the `::` operator.  Free function just means a function which is not a class member.

Comment: so lets say there weren't free functions but inside `class ff` then to use them in my program i'd have to do this?: `funcs::ff abc; abc.innerfunc();`

Comment: It's difficult to answer that because I don't know how it is defined, but let's pretend you had `namespace funcs {class ff{void innerfunc(){}};}`, you would call that as you stated.

Comment: hi, again..I thought of a situation. Take a look:  http://ideone.com/puR1Xj ...how can i define line **12** inside main. would `bar::cat::meow () {...}` work?

Comment: Basically my question would be `define function outside of class and namespace in c++?`

Comment: You cannot define a function inside a function scope.  You can just do `bar::cat::meow()` in a global scope if you want so long as it was declared inside the proper scope.  http://ideone.com/6ei6xe

Answer (score 3):

> :: (scope resolution operator) is used for multiple purposes in C++?

It's only really serving one purpose - to help find the namespace and/or class/struct/union scope that an identifier's in.

The compiler knows to look first in the tightest scope then work its way back to the global scope, but it also considers any namespaces and identifiers you're "using" (e.g. `using namespace xxx;` or `using ns1::identifier;`).

> Then you don't need to do this myclass:x.func(); Instead i can do just this x.func();

It has nothing to do with files on disk.

> Secondly, :: can be used to define class functions outside of the class like in their cpp file. Correct?

Yes.  When you define a member function outside its class, you use the class name so it's not deemed a distinct non-member function in the current scope.

> Now my additional question is that are these two functions separate or one? do they just look different to me?

Just the one in the defining-member-function scenario above.

Answer (score 1):

> Then you don't need to do this myclass:x.func(); Instead i can do just this x.func();.

Note that neither of these will compile. You cannot use the dot operator with a class; you can only use it with an object. Specifically, `myObject.func();` serves an entirely different purpose than `MyClass::func() { }`. The first **calls** the member function `func()` on the object named `myObject`. The later is used to **define** the function `func()` which belongs to the scope of `MyClass`.

Comment: are you refering to what i wrote... i wrote `class::object.func()` and `object.func()`

Comment: @MuhammadUmer Yes, I am referring to that part of your question (edited for clarity). `x.func()` will only compile if `x` is an object, not if it's a class.

Comment: @MuhammadUmer Although, what you wrote in your comment here isn't exactly what you wrote in your original question. `class::object.func()` tries to find a variable named `object` in the class named `class` (technically illegal...) and call the member function named `func()` on that object.

Comment: `object.func()` is accessing function from object. Whereas `classNamespace::object.func(){}` is defining function for some class whose declaration lives inside namespace classNameSpace.

Comment: @MuhammadUmer `classNamespace::object.func(){}` is illegal. The dot operator is used for **only** calling functions, not for defining them. `className::func() {}` is for defining a function.

Comment: ahh.. i knew that too :P, i meant `classNamespace::func()`

Comment: @MuhammadUmer I don't think you are allowed to prepend the namespace name when defining a function. Instead, it will have to be nested within a `namespace classNamespace{}` block.

Comment: so wait if `class definition` of function is inside `namespace abc`
how would you declare its function outside of file like in main.cpp

like this? : `abc::class::func(){}`

Comment: @MuhammadUmer `namespace abc { class::func(){} }`.

Comment: won't it create another namespace abc or give an error as there is already another file being included that has namespace abc. or this is how you access it

Comment: @MuhammadUmer Unlike class definitions, namespaces can span multiple translation units.

Comment: hi, again..I thought of a situation. Take a look: ideone.com/puR1Xj ...how can i define line 12 inside main. would bar::cat::meow () {...} work? `define function outside of class and namespace in c++?`

Comment: @MuhammadUmer You should post this as a brand new question.